# Contingency tables, Chi-Squared analysis and next steps in R

Tags: r, spss, chi-squared-test, survey, contingency-tables

I'm hoping one of the more experienced R programmers/statisticians out there can help me with something, or explain why what I'm trying to do is stupid :-)

In the past, I've done analysis of survey data in SPSS.  I'll often create contingency tables that uses a computed segmentation variable to see if members of the segments exhibit different behavior along an outcome variable.  Often the outcome variable is a response along a 5 or 7 point scale.  Sometimes it might be a binary yes or no.

Here is what my analysis would typically look like in SPSS:
[image]

In this case, I grouped respondents into one of 3 segments.  I then re-coded a 5-point response to q39_1 into a binary grouping of 4/5 and 1-3.  I did this because my n's were small in a few of the boxes.  You can see that the response does seem to be dependent on the respondent's segment.  The Chi-square test confirms this.

I've managed to recreate this in R using the survey package with the following code:

```
> data <- read.spss("sample_data.sav", to.data.frame=T)
> design <- svydesign(ids=~1, weights=~Weight, data=data)
> svytable(~q39_1_recode2+alt_segment, design) -> table2
> prop.table(table2,2) -> table2prop
> table2
             alt_segment
q39_1_recode2         1         2         3
            1  68.05988  88.23581  40.40518
            2  31.97007 115.05503 168.27403
> table2prop
             alt_segment
q39_1_recode2         1         2         3
            1 0.6803950 0.4340373 0.1936234
            2 0.3196050 0.5659627 0.8063766
> chisq.test(round(table2,digits=0))

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  round(table2, digits = 0)
X-squared = 71.4848, df = 2, p-value = 3.001e-16
```

Now comes the snag.  In the SPSS output, you'll notice that in the contingency table there are little subscripts that indicate where the column proportions are different from each other at an alpha of .05.  I can toggle this column proportion on or off through a checkbox when I create the table.  You can set the alpha level and then toggle a setting to adjust the p-values for multiple comparisons using the Bonferroni method.

I'm obviously not a statistician, but my assumption was that this is essentially doing the z-test equivalent of pairwise t-tests that you might see from an ANOVA analysis.  I find this type of analysis useful because not only do I now know that there is a relationship between the variables, I can now describe what that relationship is.

**So, the question is:  How do I replicate these pairwise z-tests in R while correcting for the multiple comparisons?  Is this in fact the correct "next-step" after a chi-squared test of independence?**  I've had trouble finding material that discusses what the next steps in an analysis should be after rejecting the null hypothesis in chi-sq test.  I feel like I'm either missing something that's pretty easy or I'm trying to do something that I shouldn't be.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want `svychisq` not `chisq.test` -- see examples at the bottom of `?svytable`  [the survey package homepage](http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/index.html) explains tests of association

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That makes sense.  I was basically attempting to replicate the SPSS output, but SPSS obviously wasn't applying the Rao & Scott adjustment.   I looked it up and honestly couldn't understand exactly what it was, but it does seem to be more appropriate for my uses.

Any thoughts regarding pair-wise analysis of factor levels after rejecting the null hypothesis of independence with a chi squared test?  Thanks.

Comment: write [a for loop](http://www.screenr.com/WgH8) and run some `?svyttest`